# Не удаляется класс с помощь которого выбран элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим мы выбираем элемент `var $el = $('.hi');`. так вот, почему невозможно удалить класс у этого элемента? Делаю так -  `$el.removeClass('hi');` но ноль реакций. Ошибок в консоль не выдает. Может быть браузер виноват? Использую firefox DE

```js
$hi = $('.hi');
$hi = removeClass('hi');
(!$hi.hasClass('hi')) ? $hi.html('Удален') : $hi.html('Не удален');
```

```html
  
   
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="hi">Пример</div>
```

Comment: Виноват, скорее всего, разработчик. Было бы здорово, если бы Вы написали, какой реакции Вы ожидаете. А также привели [не]работающий пример, демонстрирующий проблемное поведение.

Comment: кнопка "Выполнить код" - щелк. Объяснения требуются?

Comment: Думаю требуются объяснения.

Comment: смотрите ответ ниже

Answer (score 4):

Попробуем заменить строчку `$hi = removeClass('hi');` на  `$hi.removeClass('hi');`

```js
$hi = $('.hi');
$hi.removeClass('hi');
(!$hi.hasClass('hi')) ? $hi.html('Удален') : $hi.html('Не удален');
```

```html
  
   
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="hi">Пример</div>
```

Comment: о господе. как же стыдно. простите, за такую глупость D:

Comment: @ИльяБалабуев Не переживайте :) - так сильно. Все когда-то начинали.

Comment: это точно......

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.div');
console.log(document.querySelector('#menu'));
setTimeout(function() {
  div.classList.remove('div');

  console.log(document.querySelector('#menu'));
}, 2222)
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="div"></div>
```